# How to save audio data getting from blob url into file system and path in mysql db

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Hi i want to save a audio file path into database and audio file into my upload folder here is my code:-

```
<a class="btn btn-large btn-danger" id="ahref" target="_blank" onclick="$('#audioLayerControl')[0].save($('#ahref')[0]);"><i class="icon-fire"></i> save</a>
```

When i clicked on this link my audio which is recorded by me is saved in downloads folder and i can play it but i want to save it in my uploads folder i am getting blob url like this `blob:http%3A//localhost%3A8383/0dd9e04b-d6db-4c8c-94b5-51cfb619f725` here is its script :-

```
this.save = function save(saveLink)
    {
        var url = this.toWave().toBlobUrlAsync("application/octet-stream");

       document.getElementById("ahref").src=url;    
     var final=document.getElementById("ahref").download = new Date().toISOString() + '.wav';

    };
```

Thank you please help me.

**Updated** After using Ajax

```
var blobUrl=url;    

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
xhr.responseType = 'blob';

xhr.onload = function() {
   var recoveredBlob = xhr.response;

   var reader = new FileReader;

   reader.onload = function() {
     var blobAsDataUrl = reader.result;
     window.location = blobAsDataUrl;
   };

   reader.readAsDataURL(recoveredBlob);
};

//xhr.open('GET', blobUrl);
 xhr.open('POST', 'upload.php', true);

xhr.send(blobUrl);
```

**Upload.php**

```
<?php

error_reporting(0);

   if( isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA))
   {

   echo  $cad = $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA;

   } 

?>
```

Ouput:-`blob:http%3A//localhost%3A8383/5155c610-dec6-4e60-8ef7-e14a56aa73d2`

and in the browser url is `data:text/html;base64,YmxvYjpodHRwJTNBLy9sb2NhbGhvc3QlM0E4MzgzLzUxNTVjNjEwLWRlYzYtNGU2MC04ZWY3LWUxNGE1NmFhNzNkMg==`

Comment: You'll need to actually send it. Have a look for a file upload tutorial utilizing AJAX.

Comment: @enhzflep please look my updated code

Answer (score 0):

i'll add :

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

just before the :

```
xhr.open('POST', 'upload.php', true);
```